# getting notified when someone's address changes?

Tags: usa, address

Last time I moved some of the companies I do business with (maybe credit unions, companies that I had loans with, etc) seemed to be aware that my address had changed and updated it in their DB accordingly. My question is...  how did they learn that my address has changed? Is there some sort of notification service that USPS provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done by change of address. Many companies offer this. Here is the link for the USA.

https://postalpro.usps.com/mailing-and-shipping-services/NCOALink